# Japanese vs Chinese characters

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my app I'm displaying some user-provided text within a TextBlock.

We found that Chinese symbols were being displayed instead of Japanese symbols, even though all the language settings under Settings are set to Japan.

Having looked into the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202920(v=vs.92).aspx I am now setting the Language property of the RootFrame at startup like this:

```
RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name);
```

Now the correct (Japanese) symbols are displayed throughout the app.

Can anyone who has traveled down this path let me know if this is the right thing to do?  Is there a better way?

Comment: I thought Japanese and traditional Chinese shared the same alphabet?

Comment: Unicode 0x5203 displays differently.  In Chinese it looks like this 刃 whereas in Japanese the little detached line on the far left crosses over the first vertical line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have had to do this in our Silverlight application too - this was to get "StringFormat=c" to honour culture settings. We couldn't find a better way of doing this.

We found this on [Tim Heuer's blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx) - unfortunately the site is down at the moment so I can't summarise the post here.